# Close alerts for specific chat or user in skype?

Tags: skype, alert

How can I close alerts for specific chat or user in skype? I am trying with typing /alertsoff but this command close all skype alerts, globally for all chats.

Comment: Are you using the skype client application or the skype web service?

Comment: I use skype client application